# Passing value in VUE JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm having trouble passing value in `socket.io` and when I `console.log(data[0].name)` I get the value but if i try to access `this.name` I don't have the result that `data[0].name` has.

```
data : {
 name : ""
},  
mounted: function(){
 socket.on('getEquipData',function(data){
 this.name = data[0].name;
   })
        }
```

My event handler

```
myClick: function(val){
   socket.emit('equipData',id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the `this` context in a variable such as `self` and use that instead. The `this` that you are using is not what you are wanting.

Here is a good blog post by Ryan More that helps explain scoping and context.

http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/